# How is std::vector<bool>::reference assigned to bool type in c++?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I know `std::vector<bool>::reference` is a proxy class that is not apparent to users.

It is implicitly converted to bool when assigned to bool type.

How is it possible? type `std::vector<bool>::reference` is far far from the type bool.

Is there some compiler work under the hood?

Below is the code example

```
...
    std::vector<bool> v = { true, true, false, false, false };
    std::vector<bool>::reference vr =  v[1];
    bool b = vr; // How is it possible ?
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
...
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [user-defined conversion functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's what I looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::vector<bool>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference) defines `operator bool` to allow implicit conversion to `bool`.